# Inserting data into SQL Server database with potentially duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases on different servers, which have tables called `dbo.A`. The data is both is largely the same, but I want to make sure both tables have the same data. I've been using SQL Server June 2016 to export data from one table to the other, but the error I get is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ''. Cannot insert duplicate key in object A
>
> The duplicate key value is 'Some text here'

I know I can delete the table and reinsert the rows, but that's cumbersome and pretty bad practice. What would be the best way for me to update the data in the second database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the server as your linked server and use the following statement.

To add rows in TableA from say Serve B's Table A.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A (Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , ....)
SELECT Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , ....
FROM [LinkedServerB].[DBName].[dbo].[A] A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.A 
                   WHERE A.PK_Column = PK_Column)
```

And then use the same query on Server B to add the rows from Server A

To add rows in TableA from say Serve B's Table A.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A (Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , ....)
SELECT Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , ....
FROM [LinkedServerA].[DBName].[dbo].[A] A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.A 
                   WHERE A.PK_Column = PK_Column)
```

Comment: It doesn't give me permission to, since I don't have top level privileges. Is there a way to do it without linking servers?

Comment: Create a copy of `dbo.A` in both servers with same structure, minus the PK column's PRIMARY KEY constraint, say in a table named `dbo.A_Stage`. Now perform the same export you've been doing to both servers but point to the staging table `dbo.A_Stage`. Then, modify Ali's query `FROM [LinkedServerA].[DBName].[dbo].[A] A` to `FROM [dbo].[A_Stage] A` ~this way the data was first exported to each other's side, and the insertion was done locally. At the end of each server's script, add a `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.A_Stage` or if you don't have permission, a `DELETE FROM dbo.A_Stage` should clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you can't use a linked server can you copy the data into an empty staging table. Then run the similar insert statement but use the staging table instead of the linked table